# accessibility guidelines and support in Read the Docs?

Tags: accessibility, read-the-docs

Although several of the projects served by [Read the Docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io) have to do with accessibility, I can't find anything that discusses accessibility guidelines and support for the project as a whole. What resources can folks suggest?

Comment: What specific area are you interested in? Web accessibility, mobile accessibility, accessibility of desktop applications (and operating systems), accessibility of office documents, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Most projects that involve accessibility tend to follow the guidelines defined by the [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#guidelines). Most laws about accessibility compliance tend to point to meeting a specific level of the WCAG.

This is  useful for finding out about the requirements, but to learn more about accessibility, you can find a number of resources online with a simple google search. Personally, I've found a good site for introducing people to accessibility is [Webaim](http://webaim.org/),

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent [accessibility recommendations site](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/home_EN/index.html) that covers web, mobile (iOS + android) and editorial contents (office, pdf...).

Whatever your field of development, many useful information is well detailed and some code snippets with illustrations are available to perfectly explain some concepts.